# Difference between `writeQuery` and `writeData` in Apollo client?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client

According to the [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/local-state/) on local state management, one can use both `writeData` and `writeQuery` for appending data to the cache.

What are the best practices here? When to one over the other?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/local-state/#managing-the-cache):

> To write the data to the cache, you can use either `cache.writeQuery` or `cache.writeData`. The only difference between the two is that `cache.writeQuery` requires that you pass in a query to validate that the shape of the data you're writing to the cache is the same as the shape of the data required by the query. Under the hood, `cache.writeData` automatically constructs a query from the `data` object you pass in and calls `cache.writeQuery`.

The only difference is: do you construct the query that is passed (by calling `cache.writeQuery` directly), or do you let Apollo handle it (by calling `cache.writeData`)?

From looking at [the source](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/master/packages/apollo-cache/src/cache.ts#L114) of `cache.writeData` on GitHub, it seems that Apollo will perform some analysis on the data you give it to determine the best way to use it, while `cache.writeQuery` will straight up take the query you pass it and use that.

So, to summarise:

`cache.writeQuery`

- Pros: probably faster, provides data shape validation
- Cons: you have to provide a query yourself

`cache.writeData`

- Pros: you let Apollo handle building the query
- Cons: might be slower, no data shape validation